# Modx revo дополнение Articles и свои поля TV

Tags: modx

Добрый день! Я не так давно работаю с modx, возникла такая проблема.

На modx revo установлен модуль новостей Articles. Добавляю к статье дополнительные нужные мне TV (доступ к шаблонам статьи у них есть), называются они datetv и costtv.

Вывожу список последних статей на главной странице, код чанка, который это делает:

```
[[newstpl? &title=[[+pagetitle]] &text=[[+introtext]] &date=[[*datetv]] ]]
<p>Дата: [[*datetv]]</p>
```

Вообще нужно передать дату события в сниппет, собственно всё (title и introtext) передается и выводится, кроме TV, которые я сама определила. 
Пробовала писать так:

```
[[newstpl? &title=[[+pagetitle]] &text=[[+introtext]] &date=[[+tv.datetv]] ]]
<p>Дата: [[+tv.datetv]]</p>
```

но не сниппет, не чанк не видит эту переменную.

В настройках контейнера этой статьи включены TV:

http://clip2net.com/clip/m212830/1368451406-clip-126kb.jpg?nocache=1

Кто-то знает, как сделать правильно эти настройки? может проблема в этом

Comment: Прошу прощения сразу не увидел что у вас включен список тв в конфигурации у вас в первом вызове проблема:  &date=[[*datetv]] надо  &date=[[+datetv]]

Comment: И так не работает((

Comment: В шаблоне вызов вот такой:

[[!Articles? &container=`3`  &includeTVs=`1`]]
[[+latest_posts]]

может это неправильно?

Comment: попробуйте добавить processTVs=`1`

Comment: И так не помогает =(

Comment: [!Articles? &container=3 &includeTVs=1 &processTVs=1 &&tvPrefix= ]] везде где значения обратные кавычки